# What does Tex Live have to do with ruby?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I installed TeXlive for Ubuntu and it changed my ruby installation so that my ruby programs using statsample no longer run.  If I repair my ruby installation, what is a good way to install TeXlive that won't mess up my ruby?

Comment: Install TeXlive from here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: Might also be useful: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: Please elaborate on "no longer run". This could even be a simple collision in executable names.

Comment: afaict, the only tex live use of ruby is in support of context.  (i get this idea from looking at the distribution -- i don't know ruby, and i don't use context.)  my guess, therefore, is that if you install tex live, and then repair your ruby, you'll be ok ... unless you're a context user.

Comment: If you installed TL _from_ _Ubuntu_ and after that your ruby installation (and this was also _from_ _Ubuntu_) was broken, this is an _Ubuntu_ bug and should be handled accordingly.

Comment: I am wondering too, about why `texlive-xetex` needs ruby. I already have rubies with `asdf`, but it still requres a LOT of packages (350 MB) .